# How can I monitor multiple WordPress sites on Ubuntu better?

Tags: logging, monitoring, wordpress

Our current monitoring solution relies on logs, and our WordPress install isn't generating much in the way of them. Is there a way to get WordPress to generate more logs? Or is there a better way to monitor multiple WordPress sites on Ubuntu?

Comment: What is it you are trying to log?

Comment: The overarching goals are:
1) To look for unusual activity that might indicate a breach or compromised site.
2) Get notified of available updates and backup failures.

To that end, I would at least like to get logs that record the users who log into the admin page, log changes to the site (especially the .php files and any new files added to the site), log backups (we've already got this in place), and if possible, log when updates are available and run.